# MySQL - merge two tables - with condition

Tags: mysql, merge

I want to merge 2 tables looking like this, into a single table, and for duplicate key rows to add the oldest `DateAdded` value in the merged table.

`(Key1,Key2)` are the `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field     | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Key1      | int(10)   | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| Key2      | int(10)   | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| DateAdded | DATETIME  | NO   |     |                   |                             |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to change the table names to your specifics:

```
INSERT INTO table_merged (Key1, Key2, dateAdded)
SELECT Key1, Key2, MIN(dateAdded) dateAdded
FROM (
    SELECT Key1, Key2, dateAdded
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Key1, Key2, dateAdded
    FROM table2
  ) a
GROUP BY Key1, Key2
```

**UPDATE:**
Alternatively, this should also work:

```
INSERT INTO table_merged (Key1, Key2, dateAdded)
SELECT Key1, Key2, dateAdded
FROM table1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  dateAdded = CASE WHEN VALUES(dateAdded) < dateAdded THEN VALUES(dateAdded) ELSE dateAdded END;

INSERT INTO table_merged (Key1, Key2, dateAdded)
SELECT Key1, Key2, dateAdded
FROM table2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  dateAdded = CASE WHEN VALUES(dateAdded) < dateAdded THEN VALUES(dateAdded) ELSE dateAdded END;
```